# Mod_rewrite display subdomain.domain.com and call domain.com/subdomain/ for SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-rewrite, subdomain, godaddy

I have a website secured by a standard SSL certificate, securing a few different shops under different subdirectories. Ex. domain.com/shop1/  The shops are also accessible via a subdomain  e.g. shop1.domain.com.

What I'm trying to accomplish:  display shop1.domain.com to the user, while keeping all of the actual server calls as domain.com/shop1, so that the secure pages will continue to work properly. (Not sure if I'm using the proper language, exactly, I hope my point is clear.)

To be clear: my SSL is working fine, and I don't need help with that, and I don't need or want to purchase a UCC cert.

It can't be that difficult for anyone with experience with Apache. (I've spent 3 hours trying to learn about mod_rewrite. It's just not clicking.)  I'm on a GoDaddy secure shared server, so please keep in mind that I'm not able to reset the server or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do in fact need to purchase a more flexible SSL certificate for this to work.

The domain name that a user's browser validates the certificate against is the one that is "displayed to the user" - if their address bar says "shop.domain.com", then the certificate must cover that domain.

Comment: Ah, well bugger.  Can I do a simple redirect from, for example, shop1.domain.com to domain.com/shop1 that will work whether or not SSL is invoked by a particular page?

Comment: I'd 'Vote Up' your answer, but apparently I don't have the reputation to do so.

Comment: You can redirect from the HTTP version of the subdomain, but users would get a browser warning from the subdomain before the redirect kicks in if they visit `https://subdomain.domain.com`.  You can't upvote yet, but you should be able to mark the answer as "accepted" which awards rep by clicking the gray check mark under the voting buttons.